# Select column if no records found in translation table

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following two tables:
**`characteristics`**

```
╔════╤═══════╗
║ id │ value ║
╠════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ A     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ B     ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 3  │       ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 4  │ X     ║
╚════╧═══════╝
```

**`characteristics_translations`**

```
╔════╤════════════════════╤══════════╤══════════════╗
║ id │ characteristics_id │ language │ title        ║
╠════╪════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════════╣
║ 1  │ 3                  │ en       │ EN - Cookies ║
╟────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────╢
║ 2  │ 3                  │ fr       │ FR - Cookies ║
╟────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────╢
║ 3  │ 3                  │ de       │ DE - Cookies ║
╟────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────╢
║ 4  │ 4                  │ en       │ EN - Apples  ║
╟────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────╢
║ 5  │ 4                  │ fr       │ FR - Apples  ║
╚════╧════════════════════╧══════════╧══════════════╝
```

And I'm trying to create a query in MySQL where I select all `characteristics` with a join left to `characteristics_translations` in case there is a defined `title` in the translations table. If not, it should select the column `value` from `characteristics`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       [c.value OR ct.title] 
FROM   `characteristics` c 
       LEFT JOIN `characteristics_translations` ct 
              ON c.id = ct.characteristics_id 
WHERE  ct.language = 'de' 
        OR ct.language = NULL;
```

The output should be something like this:

```
{
  "0":{
    id: "1",
    title: "A"
  },
  "1":{
    id: "2",
    title: "B"
  },
  "2":{
    id: "3",
    title: "DE - Cookies"
  },
  "3":{
    id: "4",
    title: "X"
  },
}
```

---

**Final Solution**

```
SELECT c.id, COALESCE(ct.title, c.value) title 
FROM   `characteristics` c 
       LEFT JOIN `characteristics_translations` ct 
              ON c.id = ct.characteristics_id 
              AND ct.language = 'de'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use coalesce() to get the 1st non-null value from the list of parameters:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       coalesce(ct.title, c.value) as title
FROM   `characteristics` c 
       LEFT JOIN `characteristics_translations` ct 
              ON c.id = ct.characteristics_id 
WHERE  ct.language = 'de' 
        OR ct.language = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT c.id, COALESCE(ct.title, c.value) 
FROM   `characteristics` c 
       LEFT JOIN `characteristics_translations` ct 
              ON c.id = ct.characteristics_id 
WHERE  ct.language = 'de' 
        OR ct.language = NULL;
```

It'll return the first non-null value from a given list of parameters.